# How do I play video via a player within a LiveCode mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, video, livecode

I am able to play a video on iOS/Android with the following command-

```
 play videoClip (specialFolderPath("engine") & "/samplevidep.mov")
```

Playback works fine, but this results in the video playing back fullscreen.

Is there any way to have play a video, on mobile with the similar control/functionality of a LiveCode player object?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, you can set the `fullscreen` property of a player to false. This works on iOS only. You can also set the rect of a player. You can set these properties with

```
mobileControlSet gPlayerID,"fullscreen",false
mobileControlSet gPlayerID,"rect","0,0,600,450"
```

The documentation of LC 6.5, which I'm using today, doesn't say anything about choosing whether a movie plays full-screen or not. You could try to set the rect on Android.

Answer (score 1):

When playing a video with the Play command in a LiveCode iOS, a new player is created full screen and the video is started automatically.

Marks suggestion of setting the fullScreen and rect of player object is the method I would suggest also but you would first need to create such a player with the **mobileControlCreate** command

e.g.

```
 mobileControlCreate "player", "my_player"
```

In Marks example above, he is using the ID that is returned by the mobileControlCreate command to reference a specific control (via gPlayerID). This value can be obtained from the **Result** function after the player is created